# Schwartz "QFT and the Standard Model", eq. 15.59, derivative trick, deriving with a dot product

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vectors, differentiation, calculus

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial s}M(s)= \frac{p^{\mu}}{2s}\frac{\partial }{\partial p^{\mu}}M(s)\tag{15.59}$$

$$\ s=p^{2}$$

How does the derivative with respect to $s$ turn into the expression on the right hand side of the equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use chain rule:

$$
\partial_{p^\mu} M(s) = \partial_{p^\mu} s M'(s) = 2 p_\mu M'(s)
$$
Contract both sides w.r.t. $p^\mu$ and rearrage,
$$
M'(s)  = \frac{1}{2s} p^\mu \partial_{p^\mu} M(s).
$$